# Relation for Concave functions:

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

For a concave function, $f(\cdot)$ and that $f(0)\geq 0$, taking inputs $>0$, then we have the following relation $f(a)+f(b)\geq f(a+b)$. Assume also that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ for any $x>y$.

Does this imply that the following relation holds $(a,b,c>0)$; $$f(a+b)+f(a+c)\geq f(a+b+c)+f(a) $$I tried the following:
$$f(a+b)+f(a+c)=f\left((a+b+c)\frac{a+b}{a+b+c}\right)+f\left((a+b+c)\frac{a+c}{a+b+c}\right)$$
Then, using concavity:
$$\geq\frac{a+b}{a+b+c}f(a+b+c)+\frac{a+c}{a+b+c}f(a+b+c).$$
But dont know where if this is correct, or where if I can continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

> For a concave function, $f(\cdot)$, we have the following relation $f(a)+f(b)\geq f(a+b)$.

No we do not, not even with your extra condition that $f$ is nondecreasing. Take $f(x) = x-1$, $a=1$ and $b=0$. Then $f(a)+f(b) = -1$ while $f(a+b)=0$.

Comment: I think you meant $a=1,b=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are right, thank you

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry thats correct, I forgot to mention that $f(0)\geq 0$ (and once again only takes inputs $>0$), then it should hold. - I added this to the question.